# Unable to install cordova plugins for ios platform

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

When I add any new cordova plugin for android it installs successfully but for ios it fails with following error:

```
    Error: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'CFPropertyList' (>= 2.3.3, < 4.0) among 86 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7:/Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0:/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.9.1/libexec', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1449:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1420:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1452:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1420:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:304:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:303:in `synchronize'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:303:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.9.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Mac version: Catalina 10.15.3

Ionic: 1.1.1

cordova-android: "6.4.0"

cordova-ios: "4.5.5"

Xcode: 11

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a dependency, please install it using:

```
gem install CFPropertyList -v '3.0.2'
```